# 403 forbidden error in while searching through string in CME

Tags: search

Web 8 Tridion CME search stopped working, it says "Error occured while processing the request: Forbidden.
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
Any idea why this happened? If i search with tcm ,it works fine.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably due to configuration of the SOLR search engine, likely using a different MTSUser account or password, did you change any of this recently?

I *think* you can change the account details using the MMC snap-in.