# Search by text is not working in tridion cms after migrating to azure

Tags: search, sites-9.1, solr, azure

Search by text is not working in tridion cms though it works fine with search with tcm id after we migrated tridion to azure. whenever we try to search with any text other than tcm id, we get following error:

Error occurred while processing the request:
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 854
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.ProcessResponse(HttpWebRequest webRequest, Boolean isUpdate, Boolean isBinary, String& responseData)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Search.SolrClient.Post(String postCommand, String solrCommandUrl, String& responseData)

It seemsSolr search is not working. we tried to hit solr search url: http://localhost:8983/ on server where cms is installed but we get "HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden" error.

We have tried all options mentioned below;
Verify web contant manager snap-in for search settings(Query engine settings, Indexer service settings
Verifying solr-tomcat/config/web.xml for correct group and servername
Verifying MTS user part of correct search group.

But it didn't help yet and solr search is not working.

Please let me know if anybody has any idea about this issue.

Comment: Did you try re-indexing using the following power shell command  Sync-TcmSearchIndex

Comment: Did you try this URL - http://my.tridion:8983/#/tridion and did you try accessing using MTSUser

Comment: Please check this link  and cross verify your MTSUser - https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17473/403-forbidden-error-in-while-searching-through-string-in-cme

Comment: Yes, already all above things including re indexing by sync command and tried accessing solr url using MTS user but still its giving 403 error. Also, verified the MTS user and its correctly configured.

Comment: If the MTSUser cannot login to the SOLR connection, then I have to question the part where you say "it's correctly configured". It sure looks like something is missing, as search is still not working, and you can't login to SOLR. Maybe try re-running setup and ask it to do a repair?

Comment: What i meant by correctly configured was that we verified related items like solr-tomcat web.config for search group and servername. there doesn't seems to be issue with it. Also,  verified web contant manager snap-in for search settings(Query engine settings, Indexer service settings) to check if correct MTS user is setup and also if MTS user is part of search group. Verified tridion content manage config for user configured in search section and all those things looks okay. But i agree i will try to run the setup and repair to see if it makes difference.